# Show that the following vector space isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a space of the real vector space of all polynomials $\mathbb{P(R)}$ such that $$U=\{p\in \mathbb{P(R)}\: |\: p(-x)=-p(x)\: for \: all \: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Show that $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P(R)}$

What I think:

Consider a map that takes any polynomial (from $\mathbb{P(R)}$) to a polynomial with odd degree terms (to $U$). So we need to show that this map is a bijection.

Comment: One way to write that map: If $f(x)\in \mathbb P(\mathbb R)$ then send it to $xf(x^2)\in U.$

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the approach of finding an explicit map, as @ThomasAndrews suggests in the comments. Alternatively, you can go the nonconstructive route and just show that $\dim U = \dim P(\mathbb R)$. Indeed, the right hand side is countably infinite. Now, as $U \subseteq P(\mathbb R)$ is a subspace, we have $\dim U \leq \dim P(\mathbb R)$. The only way we could get strict inequality would be if $\dim U$ is finite. But we have the following infinite linearly independent subset: $\{x, x^3, x^5, x^7, \dots\}$ of $U$. Hence, $\dim U$ must be infinite and we get equality $\dim U = \dim P(\mathbb R)$. It's a general fact of linear algebra that vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic: just pick a bijection between the bases and extend linearly. I haven't shown you at all what this isomorphism is, so this is not the most satisfying argument, but it does work.